# Spoon run slow from Postgres to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, performance, pentaho, pdi

I have an ETL Spoon that read a table from Postgres and write into Oracle.
No transformation, no sort. SELECT col1, col2, ... col33 from table.
350 000 rows in input. The performance is 40-50 rec/sec.

I try to read/write the same table from PS to PS with ALL columns (col1...col100) I have 4-5 000 rec/sec
The same if I read/write from Oracle to Oracle: 4-5 000 rec/sec
So, for me, is not a network problem.

If I try with another table Postgres and only 7 columns, the performances are good.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Identify the slow queries and tune them.

Comment: If your Pentaho job is fast with an Oracle input and output but slow with Postgres to Oracle, I would inspect all the data types and see if it's choking on some type conversion.

Comment: Let me summarize. PS ->PS good, Oracle->Oracle: good, PS->Oracle: slow (100 times slower). And only for large tables (in number of columns). Am I correct ?

Comment: @Laurenz - Same query!!!

Comment: @Alain Yes. Also for us the problem is the data type conversion, but it's ridiculous in a data warehouse project it's normal to have different input data. 50 r/s ? I'm lucky to have only 3-5 tables with 1M rows...

Comment: @Fabiano Ok, same query, but *what* query? Figure it out and run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on that query.

Comment: select col1, col2, col3... from table very easy I read all rows

Answer (score 1):

It happened same in my case also, while loading data from Oracle and running it on my local machine(Windows) the processing rate was 40 r/s but  it was 3000 r/s for Vertica database.

I couldn't figure it out what was the exact problem but I found a way to increase the row count. It worked from me. you can also do the same.

Right click on the Table Input steps, you will see "Change Number Of Copies to Start"

Please include below in the where clause, This is to avoid duplicates. Because when you choose the option "Change Number Of Copies to Start" the query will be triggered N number of time and return duplicates but keeping below code in where clause will get only distinct records

```
where ora_hash(v_account_number,10)=${internal.step.copynr}
```

v_account_number is primary key in my case
10 is, say for example you have chosen 11 copies to start means, 11 - 1 = 10 so it is up to you to set.

Please note this will work, I suggest you to use on local machine for testing purpose but on the server definitely you will not face this issue. so comment the line while deploying to servers.

Comment: I think the issue wasn't in the input, but in the Output, so i guess the "Change Number of Copies" idea goes well in the output step, and in that there is no need to track which copy it is, PDI will sort out the output into different threads itself. This idea raises the issue of IOPS in the receiving side, maybe the receiving server has several triggers that slow down the inserts/updates, production hours/lazy hours, lots of factors at play here it seems.